# How to list all the namespaces?

Tags: adb

Right now, to list all the settings of `System` namespace I can do:

```
platform-tools/adb shell settings list system
```

To list all the settings from `Global` namespace I can do

```
platform-tools/adb shell settings list global
```

But I want to explore all the settings from all the namespaces currently installed, and for that I need to list all the available namespaces, so how do I do I get this list?

Comment: I am only aware of system, global and secure namespaces.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio , for example, there is a setting called 'Instant app' , which allows you to install instant apps, where does it go ? I can't find it in system or global

Comment: @Nulik If I'm not mistaken Instant apps is a part of Google play services and not built into Android. So it will not appear in settings.

Comment: @SSS , well, I am talking about the switch in the `Settings` to turn instant apps `On` or `Off` (https://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-instant-apps-749544/) , this is part of android installation. And I wanted to turn it on from the `adb shell`

Comment: Yes, that is managed by Google Play services. You will not be able to find it in settings via adb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are only three namespaces available: `system`, `secure` and `global`.

The settings command prints this information if you execute it without parameter:

```
adb shell settings

usage:  settings [--user <USER_ID> | current] [--cm] get namespace key
        settings [--user <USER_ID> | current] [--cm] put namespace key value
        settings [--user <USER_ID> | current] [--cm] delete namespace key
        settings [--user <USER_ID> | current] [--cm] list namespace

'namespace' is one of {system, secure, global}, case-insensitive
If '--user <USER_ID> | current' is not given, the operations are performed on the system user.
If '--cm' is given, the operations are performed on the CMSettings provider.
```

> **'namespace' is one of {system, secure, global}, case-insensitive**

Alternatively if you don't belive the settings help page you can see it in the AOSP source code. The `settings` command is implemented in the Java class [`com.android.commands.settings.SettingsCmd`](https://github.com/commaai/android_frameworks_base/blob/master/cmds/settings/src/com/android/commands/settings/SettingsCmd.java#L103) where you can see that exactly those three namespaces are accepted.